# Cannot find primary outlet to load 'LoginComponent'

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-directives

I created a simple page by reading the [Routing and Navigation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) apis of angular2. However I receive the following error,
[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh7rS.png)
Why I get this error when all configurations are correct as per angular2 RC5?

*app.routing.ts*

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component'
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'home', component: AppComponent},
    { path: '**', component: LoginComponent }
];
export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

*app.module.ts*

```
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent }  from './login.component';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { routing, appRoutingProviders } from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, MdButtonModule, MdIconModule, MdToolbarModule, MdSidenavModule, MdListModule, MdCardModule, MdInputModule, MdRadioModule, MdCheckboxModule,
        HttpModule,
        JsonpModule,
        routing,],
    declarations: [AppComponent, LoginComponent],
    providers: [
        appRoutingProviders
    ],
    bootstrap: [LoginComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

*login.component.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, COMMON_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';
import { Login } from './login.service';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute }       from '@angular/router';


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/login.html',
    styleUrls: ['styles.css'],
    providers: [LoginService],
})
```

Comment: Do you have a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your app.component.html?

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect. However I did not place this code in  app.component.html instead I have created a landing page where placed `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` code. Worked.